# Matrix of nodes with multiple lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-matrix

I am working with a binomial tree as shown below (code at end of post).

> How can I make a new line within each node? I would like to add a second number below each of the numbers in the node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
     \matrix (tree) [%
       matrix of math nodes,
       minimum size=1cm,
       column sep=2.5cm,
       row sep=0.4cm,
       column 1/.style={nodes={draw,rounded corners,
                                               top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}},
       column 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=green!30,rounded corners}},]
     {
         & 2800 \\
       2500 &  \\
        & 2700 \\
     };

     \draw[->] (tree-2-1) -- (tree-1-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
     \draw[->] (tree-2-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at section 57.2 End-of-Lines and End-of-Row Characters in Matrices of Nodes in pgfmanual.

In a `matrix of nodes` (not `matrix of math nodes` although I don't know why) you can add `text width` and `align` options and place `\\` in node contents to break lines. Multiline node contents must be inside braces `{ ... \\ ... }`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
     \matrix (tree) [%
       matrix of nodes,
       minimum size=1cm,
       column sep=2.5cm,
       row sep=0.4cm,
       column 1/.style={nodes={draw,rounded corners,
                                               top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}},
       column 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=green!30,rounded corners, text width=1cm, align=center}},
       ]
     {
         & {2800 \\ 2700} \\
       2500 &  \\
        & 2700 \\
     };

     \draw[->] (tree-2-1) -- (tree-1-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
     \draw[->] (tree-2-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]